# Select form option by data-name attribute with Behat/Selenium

Tags: html, forms, selenium, attributes, behat

I have a scenario I am creating for testing a web site using Behat / Selenium.  The form elements on the web site use a unique **"data-name" attribute**.  Behat does not recognize that attribute.  Any one have a custom step definition I can place in my FeatureContext.php that will allow me to use the "data-name" html attribute with Behat / Selenium?

```
<select name="select" data-name="state">
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        ...
        <option value="WY">WY</option>
</select>
```

The Behat error:

> When I select "MD" from "state" FeatureContext::selectOption() Form
>   field with id|name|label|value "state" not found.

Comment: That's because Behat isn't finding it, which might be either because you haven't put the below code into your (mink) context or because you didn't include that context in your `behat.yml` file and it's not loaded. Both are pretty much the same thing…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work with `When I select "MD" in the "state" select`.

```
/**
 * @When /^(?:|I )select "(?P<option>\w+)" in the "(?P<name>\w+)" select$/
 */
public function selectState($option, $name) {
    $page          = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $selectElement = $page->find('xpath', '//select[@data-name = "' . $name . '"]');

    $selectElement->selectOption($option);
}
```

Comment: This works!  Only change needed is a missing "?$/" from the end of the REGEX:  * @When /^I select "(?P<state>\w+)" state?$/

Comment: Whooops, that slipped. Well spotted!

Comment: PS: you don't need the `?` at the end there. Having it allows you to use the sentence without the last letter.

Comment: How can I modify the function above so that I can reuse to search the page for any particular "data-name"; not just state?  So if I wanted to modify the function to take the data-name as a variable that would be matched on the page...?

Comment: Unfortunately, the updated version didn't work at all.

Comment: When I select "MD" from "state" select
    /**
     * @When /^I select "([^"]*)" from "([^"]*)" select$/
     */
    public function iSelectFromSelect($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

Comment: The pattern has changed, you now should be using `When I select "MD" in the "state" select`.

Comment: It throws the same error with the correct pattern: When I select "MD" in the "state" select
    /**
     * @When /^I select "([^"]*)" in the "([^"]*)" select$/
     */
    public function iSelectInTheSelect($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using the provided code. Check that its in your context and context is loaded.

Comment: I am.  Still no luck.  I will have to revert back to the old function.  Seemed like this would be a fix but for some reason the updated function does not work.

Comment: Sorry, the problem must have been with `@When /^(?:|I ) select`, which should not have that space between the bracket and the select. Updated the code. Try again.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!! Thank you so much for your help and patience.  Your solution has saved me so much time at work!!!